# how to replace item in a list with two indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm a beginner in python and I am trying to make a hangman game but I can't seem to get it to work.
Here's my code:

```
word = "street"
letters = list(word)
dashes = ["_","_","_","_","_","_"]
guess = input("Guess the letter. ") #assuming that "e" was the input
x = [index for index, value in enumerate(letters) if value == guess]
dashes[x] = guess
```

I want to replace in dashes in `dashes` that have the indexes in `x`.  In the case of `"e"` being the input that means `dashes[3]` and `dashes[4]` become `"e"`.  `dashes[x] = guess` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you give the expected output?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please elaborate on how you "can't seem to get it to work"?

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to build a new list `dashes` and reassign the name after each guess than to maintain a list of dashes which you mutate.

Demo:

```
>>> word = 'street'
>>> dashes = ['_']*len(word)
>>> 
>>> guess = 'e'
>>> dashes = [guess if letter == guess else current
...:          for letter, current in zip(word, dashes)]
>>> dashes
>>> ['_', '_', '_', 'e', 'e', '_']
>>> 
>>> guess = 't'
>>> dashes = [guess if letter == guess else current
...:          for letter, current in zip(word, dashes)]
>>> dashes
>>> ['_', 't', '_', 'e', 'e', 't']
```

Answer (score 1):

A direct continuation of the code you already wrote is to loop over the indices in `x`:

```
for i in x:
   dashes[i] = guess
```

Alternatively, you could combine the list comprehension and the loop:

```
for i in range(len(word)):
    if dashes[i] == '_' and word[i] == guess:
        dashes[i] = guess
```

Personally, I use NumPy a lot and feel that's it's a pretty good fit for this problem:

```
import numpy as np
word = np.array(list("street"))
dashes = np.full_like(word, "_")
guess = input("Guess the letter. ")
dashes[word == guess] = guess
```

No Python loops, just vectorized computation. :)

Comment: Ah.. didn't see this, you beat me to it.

Comment: Will edit mine.

Answer (score 1):

Or `list comprehension`:

```
print([v if i not in x else guess for i,v in enumerate(dashes)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete solution:

```
word = "street"
guessed = "_" * len(word)
attempts = 0
while '_' in guessed:
    guess = input("Guess the letter:: \n> ")
    guessed = [x if guess != letter else guess for letter, x in zip(word, guessed)]
    print(' '.join(guessed))
    attempts += 1
    if attempts > 7:
        print('Too many wrong guesses.. You lose.')
        break
else:
    print('CONGRATULATIONS!')
```

Comment: `guessed = ["_" for _ in word]` => `guessed = "_"*len(word)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
word = "street"
dashes = ['_'] * len(word)

guess = raw_input("Guess the letter. ")

dashes = map(lambda x: x if x == guess else '_', word)
```

map applies a function to every element of a list. lambda is a nameless function.